# Making a method that creates an image with X in square using stars

Tags: java

I am supposed to complete the inside of a method

```
      public static void printXinSquare(int width) {

          }
```

width being the number of rows so that it would create

```
  * * * * * * * *
*   * * * * * *   *
* *   * * * *   * *
* * *   * *   * * *
* * * *     * * * *
* * * *     * * * *
* * *   * *   * * *
* *   * * * *   * *
*   * * * * * *   *
  * * * * * * * *
```

I've tried making four separate pieces of triangles, and attach them somehow, but that didn't work.

I also tried to create a for loop for spaces and then add a for loop for the stars, but I'm confused and have no idea as to how to do that.

To do this, as I said before, I tried to make separate trianges.

```
  public static void printXinSquare(int width) {


  for (int i = 1; i <= width/2+1; i++) {
     for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {

        System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
  for (int i = width/2+2; i <= width; i++) {
     for (int j = width+1-i; j >= 1; j--) {

        System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.println();
 }
```

This creates a triangle pointing to the right.

```
  public static void printXinSquare(int width) {

  for (int line = width/2+1; line >1; line--) {
     for (int i = 1; i <= (line - 1); i++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
     }
     for (int i = 1; i <= (width    - 2 * line); i++) {
        System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
```

This creates a triangle pointing upwards.

This is what I have tried so far, but I don't think this way works.

I think I should create for loops that take into account the spaces,

but I don't know how to do that as the spaces are in diagonal direction.

Any help to complete this method would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What is the width in above case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should print in with an input width of `10` the exact picture you have in your question.

```
public static void printXinSquare(int width) 
{
    for (int k = 0; k < width; k++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            if (k == j || k == width - j - 1) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It prints `*` with a blank space every time to ensure it is properly spaced out like that picture, and prints *2* spaces instead in two different cases, each of which account for a single diagonal line.  The two cases are as follows:

`if` the row count is equal to the current column count, there should be a space instead of an asterisk.  This will create the first diagonal line going from top left to bottom right.

`if` the row count is equal to the `width` minus the current column count minus `1`, it also should be a space rather an asterisk.  This will create the second diagonal line going the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks! You're literally a genius :) Your solution is something I couldn't even think of!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    if (i == j || i+j == width) {
       System.out.print(" ");
    } else {
       System.out.print("*");
    }
  }
  System.out.println("");
}
```

In this case you would be printing `'*'` when it is not in the triangle, and `' '` otherwise. The inside triangle is the condition `(i==j || i+j==width)`